# Check if a file contains an exact match string from another file using grep

Tags: grep

I have two files : file1 and file2. The content of both files is the following

- file1: Hello
- file2: Bla bla bla bla Hello Bla Bla bla bla bla

My objective is to see if I can find an exact match of **Hello** in **file2**.

---

I used the following command: `grep -F -f file1 file2`. As output I get `Bla bla bla bla Hello Bla Bla bla bla bla`.

But suppose I change **Hello** in file1 to just **"H"** and I run the grep command again 
; I also get as output  `Bla bla bla bla Hello Bla Bla bla bla bla`.

What can I do in order to solve that problem and search only for an exact match?

Comment: You are getting an exact match. If you want to match a complete word, use `-w` with grep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add those two arguments:

- **-w** Matches only word/words instead of substring
- **-o** Display only matched pattern instead of whole line

So command will be:

```
grep -ow -F -f file1 file2
```

First exemple will output:

```
Hello
```

Second one won't output anything since there is no exact match found.

Comment: The second example would not output anything as there is no `H` word in the data.